# How to get product custom attribute drop-down appear on frontend?

Tags: magento2, product, attributes, custom

Basically I have to create a drop-down of "brands" on my product page such that customers can manually select their brands depending on their choice. What is the way to do this?

Is it possible to create a custom attribute of brands in the admin panel then show that dropdown of brands in the frontend such that customers can select their choice of brand manually?

By the way, I have created the dropdown of brands in the admin panel, I want to show this dropdown in the frontend also..

Thanks!!

Comment: Please review this question with answers, looks like it would suit your requirement: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132807/how-to-get-the-attribute-values-for-multiselect-in-magento-2

Comment: You can check with this link..   https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-product-custom-options-in-magento-2.html